# Python: Reading Logging Level from a Config File and avoiding previous DEBUG Information not getting lost

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have the following python code where logging level of a global logger is set through a Command-line argument:

```
logging.basicConfig (
    level = getattr (logging, clArgs.logLevel),
    ...
```

If no logging level has been specified through CL argument, then by default INFO log level is used for global logging:

```
# Define '--loglevel' argument
clArgsParser.add_argument (
    "-l", "--loglevel",
    help = "Set the logging level of the program. The default log level is 'INFO'.",
    default = 'INFO',                       # Default log level is 'INFO'
    dest = "logLevel",                      # Store the argument value into the variable 'logLevel'
    choices = ['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL']
)
```

Now I would like to give a 2nd option to the user, so that the logging level can be also specified in a Configuration File. Nonetheless, before the Configuration file is read out the script must first read out the CL arguments to figure out if the user has set the log level CL argument. Additionally, the configuration file path can be also specified through a CL argument.
After the script reads out the CL arguments and sets the logging level, it stores some logging information (e.g. log file location, directory where the script is being executed, etc.) as well it stores the **DEBUG** logging information while reading out the config file in the function **readProgramConfig**. The config file is read out at the very end (function **readProgramConfig**) as you can see in the code snippet below:

```
# Parse the Command-line Arguments
clArgs, progName = parseClArgs ( __program__ )

# Initialize Global Logging with Command-line Arguments
defaultLogFilePath = configLogging ( clArgs )

# Log Program Version used
logging.info ( f"Program version: {__program__.swVersion}")

# Log Script Start Time
logging.info ( f"Program start time: {programStartDate}" )

# Log the program's current directory
logging.debug ( f"Directory where the Program is being executed: {PROGRAM_DIR}" )

# Output the log file location
logging.debug ( f"Log file location: {defaultLogFilePath}")

# Read out the program configuration
programConfig = readProgramConfig ( clArgs.programConfigPath )
```

This leads to a problem - if no log level is specified through the CL argument and the log level is specified by the user in the config file (e.g. **DEBUG**), then the following will happen:

1. No CL-Arg for log level specified -> use **INFO** log level per default
2. Do logging (program version, program start time) before reading out the config file -> however, no **DEBUG** level information is logged as **INFO** is used by default
3. Additionally, no **DEBUG** information is logged while reading out the config file (function **readProgramConfig**)
4. Once the config file has been read out, the script will figure out that the config file wants to set the log level to **DEBUG**, and will then try to change the global logging level from **INFO** to **DEBUG**
5. From now on all **DEBUG** information will be logged, however the previous **DEBUG** information is lost, i.e. never logged

So it's sort of like a hen and egg problem.

I do have one solution in mind, but it is rather complicated and I would like to find out if someone of you have a simpler solution.

One possible solution would be:

1. Start the script with **DEBUG** log level by default to capture all log messages
2. Read out the config file:

   2.1 If the log level in the config file is set to **DEBUG**, then continue logging into the log file with the **DEBUG** log level.

   2.2 If the log level in the config file is set to lower log level than **DEBUG** (e.g. **INFO**), then delete all **DEBUG** entries in the log file, and continue logging only using the **INFO** log level.

You see the solution is rather complicated - it involves editing the log file and writing back and forth ... Not to mention that this approach will not work for logging into the console ...

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use [logging.config](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.dictConfig) python module. You can read a config file (e.g. in JSON format) and store it as a dictionary. The module provides function `logging.config.dictConfig` which will configure the logger using the information from the config file, i.e. dictionary. The code for configuring the root logger would look something like this:

```
import logging                                 # Logging
from logging import config as LogConfig        # Logging Configuration

# Create the Log File name
logFileConfigName = "LogConfig.json"
logFileConfigPath = os.path.join ( PROGRAM_DIR, logFileConfigName )

# Open the JSON Config File
jsonLogConfigFile = open ( logFileConfigPath )

# Decode the JSON Config File
jsonLogConfig = json.load ( jsonLogConfigFile )

# Take the logging configuration from a dictionary
LogConfig.dictConfig ( jsonLogConfig )
```

The logger configuration would be stored in the `LogConfig.json` file. For both console and file logging there is a seperate handler defined in the config file:

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "root":
    {
        "handlers" : ["console", "file"],
        "level": "DEBUG"
    },
    "handlers":
    {
        "console":
        {
            "formatter": "std_out",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler"
        },
        "file":
        {
            "filename" : ".\\Program.log",
            "formatter" : "std_out",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "mode": "w"
        }
    },
    "formatters":
    {
        "std_out": 
        {
            "format": "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s: %(message)s",
            "datefmt":"%Y-%m-%d - %H:%M:%S"
        }
    }
}
```